# uninitialized constant and remove minutes selector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have the following controller

```
class Dashboard::AvailabilitiesController < Dashboard::ApplicationController

  def index

  end

  def new

  end

  def create
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

with this model:

```
class Availability
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :class_date,        type: DateTime

  belongs_to :kid

  validates_uniqueness_of :class_date, :scope => [:class_date, :kid_id]
end
```

and this route:

```
namespace :dashboard do
  resources :kids do
    resources :availabilities
  end
end
```

on my view, I have the following form:

```
= form_tag dashboard_kid_availabilities_url(current_kid), :method => 'post', :multipart => true do
            .form-group
              = datetime_select :class_date, {:start_year => Time.now.year, :order => [:day, :month, :year], :discard_minute => true}
            .form-group
              = submit_tag _('Save'),  class: 'btn btn-blabloo btn-xs'
```

But I'm getting "uninitialized constant Dashboard::AvailabilitiesController" and I don't understand why. Also, I can remove the minutes selector of the forme using the discard_minute => true.

Any Idea please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you succeeded with the issue?

Comment: yes, it was the controller file name. But I still need help hiding the minutes fields.

Comment: hey Jean, would you be so nice to accept the answer which resolved your error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe controller name should be within module Dashboard

```
  module Dashboard
    class AvailabilitiesController < ApplicationController

      def index

      end

      def new

      end

      def create
      end

      def destroy
      end
    end
end
```

Another option is, probably, `class Dashboard::AvailabilitiesController < ApplicationController`.

Also make sure, that controller in under `/controllers/dashboard/avaliabilities_controller.rb`